# How to catch all errors in route as a middleware in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a problem and I haven't found a solution yet. I want to catch all errors if occur any error in each route **but it's very inconvenient when I have to do it many times.**

How can i implement it as a middleware same like `app.use(ErrorHandle);` ?

*Code in ErrorHandler.js:*

```
export const ErrorHandler = func => async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        await func(req, res, next);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}
```

*Code in index.js*

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err) {
    return res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);  
  }
  next() 
});
```

Code in route need to catch error:

```
import { ErrorHandler } from './ErrorHandler';

export const uploadMedia = ErrorHandler(async (req, res) => {
  // do something...
  let error = new Error();
  error.statusCode = 404;
  error.message = 'Content not found!';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if misunderstood your question... When you do the code below which you provided, you are assuming that if an error reaches the end of the stack via `next(err)`, such handler should be called. Hence it's the last declaration after all your routes.

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err) {
    return res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);  
  }
  next() 
});
```

That, however, won't catch `unhandledExceptionErrors`. You still need the good old

```
try {
 // throw error somewhere
} catch (e) {
 next(e);
}
```

Personally, I haven't tried [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-promise-router) but it seems so be a nice hack for Express router's inability to handle promise returns. About express-promise-router:

> A simple wrapper for Express 4's Router that allows middleware to return promises. This package makes it simpler to write route handlers for Express when dealing with promises by reducing duplicate code.